# Does Flask Rate Limiter work with Elasticache (Redis 2.8)?

Tags: flask, redis, amazon-elasticache

My large-scale web application currently uses Python Flask rate-limiter. I have several Amazon EC2 instances running the application. And the Flask rate-limiter relies on Redis instances I have setup. I'm using Redis 3.0.

I'm interested in replacing my Redis instances with [Amazon Elasticache For Redis](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/redis/). Elasticache supports Redis 2.8. So I will be downgrading from Redis 3.0.

Does Flask rate-limiter use any features found in Redis 3.0 that are not found in Redis 2.8? If not, I should not run into any trouble. But the Flask Rate-limiter [documentation](https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) doesn't say what version of Redis it requires/uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask limiter depends on limits module as seen here:

https://github.com/alisaifee/flask-limiter/blob/master/flask_limiter/extension.py#L12

```
from limits.storage import storage_from_string, MemoryStorage
from limits.strategies import STRATEGIES
```

The [limits module](https://github.com/alisaifee/limits/blob/master/limits/storage.py): just implements `get,set,incr` operations of redis or memcached.

**Redis 2.8 and Redis 3.0 are exactly the same in these basic operations.**

The only thing you will miss by downgrading to 2.8 is non-availability of redis cluster features, which are not of user in a small data requirement case like throttling.